# Get All the Rows from RIGHT TABLE - Eloquent Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hi I need all the rows from **Right Table**, but I'm getting only one last row from the **LEFT JOINED TABLE**.

Table Structure is as follows:

> Table:  news

```
id | user_id(pk) | title | name
```

> Table:  news_comments

```
id | user_id(pk) | news_id(pk) | comment
```

What I have tried is as follows:

```
News::select('news.*', 'users.username', 'users.avatar')
                    ->selectRaw('news_comments.comment')
                    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'news.user_id')
                    ->leftJoin('news_comments', function ($join) {
                        $join->on('news_comments.news_id', '=', 'news.id')
                        ->on('news_comments.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
                    })->get();
```

But this query is returning only one last column. I want all the comments which belong to each news. I have also tried with the ELoquent Relationships, but I think I was wrong at some point. Please help me out with this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.title,b.name,a.comment from news_comments a left join news b on a.user_id = b.user_id;
```

This returns all records from news_comment even if corresponding record absent in news.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, but I had made a mistake while asking the question, just now I realized by your comment and corrected the question. I want all rows from the Table which is left joined. It means I want all the rows from table news_comments

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used laravel and eloquent but still as per mysql knowledge when you left join your news table to news_comment table, it will fetch all records from news table and show last comment from news_commet table corresponsing to news primary key and NULL values if comments not available. But what you need is all comments from news_comment and show its corresponding details from news table
so you have to use the left join query as below, not sure it will work or not

```
DB::table('news_comments')
        ->leftJoin('news', 'news_comments.user_id', '=', 'news.user_id')
        ->get();
```

By this query you will get all comments from news_comment table and details from news table

Comment: Hi okay I will try this way

Comment: Nope but this won't work, as I need foreach LOOP of News, this will return me the array of all comments

Comment: But from your question I have understood that you require this. as you have written "I want all the comments which belong to each news"

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do it. I did it by the following way:

```
$news = News::select('news.*', 'users.username', 'users.avatar')
                    ->selectRaw('(select count(*) from news_comments where news_comments.news_id = news.id) as comment_count')
                    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'news.user_id')
                    ->get();
```